# The window of calender is out of the screen

Tags: panel

I've been using a external 21.5' monitor for my laptop of 12.1' monitor, and moved my top panel to the right and add a new panel to the bottom edge of the screen. A screenshot of the right part of my desktop:

[image]

As you see, The window of the calender is out of the screen. The alt+left mouse button did not work. How do you move the calender window?

update:
I managed to come up with a solution to get the window or panel of cal in the screen. Just remove the panel of clock and re-add it. But unfortunately, the preferences are lost. You have to reset the preferences, such as locations...

but after re-adding 2 locations, the window of cal panel was just shown as the same of the previous screenshot before.

Answer (score 2):

Right Click on the Date/Time, and Move. Now the Popup will come to the location where you have put your date/time.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYRxg.png]

Comment: yes. but it will only move the part on the taskbar, not the calender part